# jQuery and last-child not working in IE8

Tags: jquery

I'm tearing my hair out over this one - its driving me mad because it should be so simple.

In my site i use `:last-child` to remove the `border-bottom` from the last element of a twitter feed:

```
ul#twitter li:last-child {
    border: none;
}
```

This works fine in Firefox / Chrome, but not IE8 which doesn't support last-child. So, i turned to jQUery and put this in my `<head>`

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){  
            $('ul#twitter li:last-child').css('border','none !important');
        });
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

This has no effect? Ive tried using an external file, making it not IE8 specific, with and without document ready... Ive also tried tested the selector in Firebug to make sure my jQuery is correct and it all works? Any ideas?

[The site is here](http://bit.ly/tG5F34)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is just fine, the problem happens because you include the `jQuery` library at the bottom of the page, but your run your IE8 script at the top.

jQuery is not loaded yet, so your script fails (*and throws an error as well, **`'$' is undefined`***)

Move the code after the jQuery inclusion and you should be set.

Comment: I thought that - but isnt that the point of `$(document).ready(function(){` ?

Comment: @ryan, but `$` does not exist yet.. the point is to allow the DOM to be loaded, but you **have** to load jQuery before using it..

Comment: `if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 8) {` in my functions.js did the trick - thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try using `:last` instead of `:last-child`:

```
$('ul#twitter li:last').css(...)
```

For reference, `:last-child` looks for the last child element within the set - so in your case would look for the last child element of inside the `li` elements within `ul#twitter`.

`:last` just looks for the last element within the set, so for you would match the last `li` itself within `ul#twitter`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is better to use

```
$('ul#twitter li').last();
```

or

```
$('ul#twitter li:last');
```

as your selector

Comment: `$('ul#twitter li').last().css('border','none');` also didnt work (live on the site now)